# What are Recommended Ways to Optimize Memory and Usability Speed of custom UITableViewCells with multiple UIImages?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I am using a custom UITableViewCell with 3 UIImages in a UITableView with 50-100 rows. Its similar to a UITableViewCell the Facebook iPhone app uses for its news feed view.

The application has 4 similar UITableViews which may be open at the same time via a UITabConroller.

The images are lazy loaded, there is a cache on disk so that no images are loaded twice from the server and there is also a NSMutableDictionary for images allowing in-memory reuse of the same image eg: a users profile picture appears multiple times

This setup is extremely fast but takes a lot of memory even after using the NSMutableDictionary for image reuse.

I tried a variation without the NSMutableDictionary where images are either loaded from the server or pulled from the disk cache every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. This setup is extremely memory efficient but causes a noticeable lag in the UITableView scrolling.

A mid-way approach is to free the NSMutableDictionary for images when a low memory warning is received.

Will really appreciate recommendations to optimize memory usage and speed in this scenario and or an insight into how the Facebook iphone app or three20 execute this conceptually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an app that is very similar to yours in many respects (uses Three20, has several tabs across the bottom, each tab can have a table, each cell can have one or two images); and the approach I'm taking is the one you mentioned near the end of your post:

> A mid-way approach is to free the NSMutableDictionary for images when a low memory warning is received.

Personally, I quite like iOS's approach to memory management, of warning me when memory is getting tight.  The Mac/PC approach of "just use all the memory you want, we'll swap it out to disk if memory gets tight" has the disadvantage that even though the OS is the only one who really knows how much pressure there is on memory, it isn't telling you.  I think what every polite app would really like to say (if apps could talk) is, "I'd be happy to use as much memory as you'll give me, but I don't want to be a bother, I don't want to slow down any other apps, so if you could please give me a hint as to how much memory I can use without causing problems, I would appreciate it."

Well that's what iOS's memory warnings give you, in my opinion.  So, just keep as many images cached in memory as you want; and when you get a memory warning, empty the in-memory cache.  To me it's really the best of both worlds.

Also, you should definitely take a look at Three20's `TTURLCache`, although I can't tell you a lot about it because I haven't dug into it very much.  What I do know is:

- If you retrieve your messages via `TTURLImageResponse`, it will automatically cache them in `TTURLCache`'s image cache.
- You can also store and load your own images (and other data) in the `TTURLCache`.

Three20 seems to take an approach similar to what I am talking about.  Take a look at this code from Three20Network/Sources/TTURLCache.m (the `NO` argument means don't remove from disk, only remove from memory):

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning:(void*)object {
  // Empty the memory cache when memory is low
  [self removeAll:NO];
}
```

In addition, that class also allows you to set a maximum size for the in-memory cache, but by default there is no maximum size.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I found three20 a little intimidating when I started iOS development so ended up making my own NSURLConnection wrapper. I am leaning towards the midway approach but can't help but feel there should be a cleaner way. By the time I get a low warning memory iOS has mysteriously purged a UIView somewhere in the app causing a crash soon afterwards. Not sure if that is normal behavior after a low memory warning or the result of a memory leak. Please share any insights from working on a feed implementation using a UITableView.

Comment: The only suggestion I can think of is, it's normal for other UIViews to be "unloaded" when memory gets tight (their `viewDidUnload` function gets called); regardless of what memory management approach you take, you still need to make all your views robust in the face of potentially being unloaded.  This means your view might see this call sequence: init, viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, viewDidLoad, viewDidLoad, viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, dealloc.  Also, note that viewDidUnload is not necessarily called before dealloc is called.

Answer (score 1):

you would purge images when they go offscreen, then read the images from the locale cache on demand from a secondary worker thread when needed. since one can zip through tables, add support for read cancellation (esp. for requests which come off the server). NSOperation is a good api for this.

if you know your table's small, then you could opt to avoid purging in such cases.

also, rescaling the image to the size you'll display it as is often a good idea (depending on how far you want to take an optimization). assuming the source is larger than the displayed size: this will reduce memory requirements, drawing speed, disk space, and disk read times.

you can also read three20's sources to see what they have done.

Comment: Thanks Justin. My images are resized server side for the optimizations you mentioned. I tried purging images as they go offscreen and pulling them from a local cache when they are needed. If I do this using NSOperation or any form of lazy loading the UIImage goes blank for a second until it is pulled from the cache in a separate thread which is alright the first time but users expect to see images instantly when they scroll back up. Also, if I pull it while blocking the main thread there is a tiny but noticeable lag. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sid you're welcome. for large tables, you must purge in some applications. otherwise, you'll run out of memory, as you would expect. a table can be traversed too quickly to logically cache a ton of images (if you cap it somehow, that changes things). i've used an activity indicator in addition to delaying the load invocation (which helps when the user scrolls quickly). you could purge/load images which are *n* indices from the visible range in order improve this... (cont)

Comment: (cont) but that's a bit of a pain to manage and you'll lose cell reuse so you'll end up with a ton of auxiliary allocations for all those offscreen views. with 50-100 you could get away with an activity indicator and deferred loading/purging np if your app has a small memory footprint otherwise. as far as UX, i think it's fine to defer the load and purge in this manner. if the images are very small, you may be able to keep them in memory once loaded. lastly, if you know you're reusing some of the images, then share them.

Comment: I tried to look for a delegate method similar to cellForRowAtIndexPath that fires when a cell is removed from the UITableView. The closest I got is to check the dealloc method of my custom cell to know when its freed. I really like the idea of loading from a local disk cache but can't get over the performance compromise. Wil probably go with keeping an in-memory cache of UIImages and purging them on a low memory warning. Any insights on handling low memory warnings? I don't respond to them right now and iOS mysteriously purges UIViews in my app. Memory leak or normal low memory behavior?

Comment: `- [UITableViewCell prepareForReuse]` would work if you were to subclass and extend the cell appropriately. i was in the same position: i had no superior alternative. i had to purge. there were multiple images per cell, and images which filled the cell. again, cancellation support and inserting a delay to the load can improve load speeds -- there's less contest. beyond that, you may have to reduce the image size (not dimensions, but pixel format) directly, in order to reduce memory consumption (that's too far for most apps, and would require a bit of additional cpu during render).

Comment: insights on low-mem: i cleanup much of what is offscreen in order to avoid them in commercial level apps. i add checks to see if the request is made, and further reduce consumption in implementation if it's called. not much is released if it's called in this case. (cont)

Comment: (cont) you could create a custom image view which (if referencing an on disk representation) is able to purge its image, and reload on demand - lazy reload. images and web views are a common source for high alloc sizes, but a lot of the rest is app specific. sometimes you can purge audio/video files in the same manner, if you use a lot of audio/video files.